# c# ado.net sqlparameter fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I am passing sqlparameter in localize language (Persian) from c# but no rows retrieves. Database already collate for persioan_100_ci_ai and tables are collate database_default

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataReader dr = default(SqlDataReader);
dt.TableName = "temp";
try {
    if (!(conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed))
        conn.Close();
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    string qry = "Select * from users WHERE [Name]=@UserName AND [Pwd]=@Password";
    cmd.commandtext = qry;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "ادمین";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = "ادمین";
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    if (dr.HasRows) {
        dt.Load(dr);
    }

    return dt;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    return null;
} finally {
    dt = null;
    cmd.Connection = null;
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

It works in SSMS

```
declare @UserName nvarchar(50) = 'ادمين'
declare @Password nvarchar(50)= 'ادمين'
select * from Users where [name]=@UserName and [Pwd] = @Password
```

It even works when I am embedding variables in query instead of parameter

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataReader dr = default(SqlDataReader);
string pLoginName = "ادمین";
string pPassword = "ادمین";
dt.TableName = "temp";
try {
    if (!(conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed))
        conn.Close();
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    string qry = "Select * from users WHERE [Name]='" + pLoginName + "' AND [Pwd]='" + pPassword + "'";
    cmd.CommandText = qry;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    if (dr.HasRows) {
        dt.Load(dr);
    }

    return dt;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    return null;
} finally {
    dt = null;
    cmd.Connection = null;
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

Cannot figure out where I am wrong.
Please, if any one can point out.

Comment: use cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue, any difference?

Comment: @HamidP: **DO NOT** use `AddWithValue`! Check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: you are right marc - here we are declaring the parameter with type. So inner library have not work to determine the type of pararameter value you are passing. Specifically here when the parameter must be "Nvarchar" as it uses unicode

Comment: still Tried the AddWithValue but same results dr.hasrows = false.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", "ادمین"));
```

EDIT:

Lets try a different way. If you're up for some re-coding. I will post an example from an old college project that works. It's essentially the same concept. May not be the best way but it works...

I used a DataAdapter, a DataSet, and a GridView control on an .aspx page. You tagged ASP.net, but I am not sure what you're trying to use to display the data.

```
string selectsql2 = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].Event_View WHERE (EventName LIKE '%' + @EventName + '%')";
SqlConnection connect2 = new SqlConnection(connectionstring2);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectsql2, connect2);
SqlParameter pm = new SqlParameter("@EventName", txtEvents.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add(pm);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds2);
gvEvents.DataSource = ds2;
gvEvents.DataBind();
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Tried the same but same results dr.hasrows = false.

Comment: still Tried the AddWithValue but same results dr.hasrows = false

Comment: Maybe you can try a different approach? Using a DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any problems, I add both values to my test database. Here is the sample code

```
        // Code in BO logic method
        string email = "ادمین";
        string password = "ادمین";


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Register WHERE Email=@Email AND Deleted=0 AND Password=@Pass");

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Email", email.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Pass", password.Trim());

        DataSet dst = Varmebaronen.AppCode.DA.SqlManager.GetDataSet(cmd);

    //DataAccess Methods !
    public static DataSet GetDataSet(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        return GetDataSet(cmd, "Table");
    }

    public static DataSet GetDataSet(SqlCommand cmd, string defaultTable)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection(cmd);

        try
        {
            DataSet resultDst = new DataSet();

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(resultDst, defaultTable);
            }

            return resultDst;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

`DataSet` had one record, try to use `AddWithValue`. If again nothing happen the problem is not in the parameters !

P.S Don't use one static connection, application pool is your **friend** !

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Tried AddWithValue but same results dr.hasrows = false.

Answer (score 0):

Try seperating out the parameter and value assignment like below:

```
// Create the parameter objects as specific as possible.
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);

    // Add the parameter values.  Validation should have already happened.
    cmd.Parameters["@UserName"].Value = "ادمین";
    cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value = "ادمین";
```

Comment: Tried the same but same results dr.hasrows = false.

Comment: can you try dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();